# Filling a screen with 3 divs

Tags: html, css

I have the following situation:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

`div1` and `div3` have a fixed width of `100px` and a height of `100%`, `div3` also has a height of `100%`.
What i want is for `div1` to float left, `div3` to float right and `div2` should take the remaining space between them. I cant seem to get it to work.

Any help?

Comment: Is `div2` expected to wrap around `div1`?

Comment: You are looking for a 3 column layout?

Comment: A 3column layout is what i'm looking for indeed, but if i hava a screen of lets say 1440px wide, and the left div is 100px, and the right div is 100px then the middle div should take up all the space between it. in this case, 1240px

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write like this:

**CSS:**

```
#div1{
    float:left;
    background:red;
    width:100px;
}
#div3{
    float:right;
    background:green;
    width:100px;
}
#div2{
    overflow:hidden;
    background:blue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/D8836/

**UPDATED**

If you want equal height then you can use `display:table` property for this. Check this

http://jsfiddle.net/D8836/11/

Comment: The problem with this is that the columns will not be the same height: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWaxMann/D8836/9/)

Comment: @sandeep the problem is that the height of the 3 divs has to be 100%, this doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 2):

This one doesn't require you changing the order of your divs, but does require CSS3 (flex box). http://jsfiddle.net/pPEmZ/